# Setting up a cursor with LWJGL

Tags: java, cursor, lwjgl

I don't understand how to create a cursor with a custom image with the Lightweight Java Game Library.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the opengl window in a swing frame. (Add canvas to frame and set the display parent) you might be able to change the cursor for with the frame. Otherwise just disable the cursor and draw a new one and translate it by the mouse position.